# Postgresql inner select with distinct

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm using Postgresql 9.2 and have a simple students table as follow

```
id | proj_id | mark | name | test_date
```

I have 2 queries which is described below

```
select * from (select distinct on (proj_id) proj_id , mark, name, 
test_date from students )
t 
where t.mark <= 1000
```

**VS**

```
select distinct on (proj_id) proj_id , mark, name, test_date from   
students where mark <= 1000
```

when I run each query for more than 10000 records each query returns different result especially result count although for less than 3000 records the result would be the same.

is this postgresql 9.2 bug or I'm missing something ?

Comment: `distinct on` without an `order by` doesn't make sense. Rows in a relational database have no implied order. Without an `order by` the database is free to return them in any order it thinks is most efficient

Comment: the problem is not about order, some result will lost the first query will return less row than the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Your queries are producing two different sets of results because they are applying the logic differently.

- The first query is getting a distinct set of results, and then applying the 'mark' filter.
- The second query is applying the 'mark' filter, and then getting a distinct set of results.

As you don't have any ordering applied the first query could potential return a different number of rows each time it is run - as the `mark` field could contain any of the values that relate to the `proj_id`.

Comment: you mean if I apply order by the result would be the same ? I need to get same result

Comment: Yes - if you applied an `ORDER BY mark DESC` to the sub query in the first query it should produce the same results.

Comment: I have 15000 records in student table and the query `select * from (select distinct on (proj_id) proj_id , mark, name, 
test_date from students ORDER BY proj_id, mark DESC)
t where t.mark <= 1000`
returns nothing